# Is casting a constructor parameter from interface type to concrete class type wrong here?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Given is the following class:

```
public interface ISession {}

public class Session : ISession
{
    internal Uri ServerUri { get; private set; } // not in interface obviously
}
```

Now I have another class in the same project which depends on `Session`:

```
public  interface IDataClass {}

internal DataClass : IDataClass
{
    private readonly Session _session;

    public DataClass(ISession session)
    {
        _session = (Session) session;
    }

    // some more methods that access the internal property _session.ServerUri
    // and call methods on the session object
    // ...
}
```

So actually the Session class is pretty complex. For unit testing the `DataClass` I made the constructor parameter an `ISession`, so I was able to mock the dependency and verify certain method calls on the `ISession` mock.

However, some methods in the `DataClass` have to access the `_session.ServerUri` property, so the field has to be of type `Session` rather than `ISession`.

I could also make the field of type `ISession` and cast the field everytime I access the internal property which would make it more clear in this specific location why the concrete, `internal` class is even needed.

Everytime I implement casts in the above way I wonder somehow if with better code design the cast could have been avoided. Oftentimes I found a better way and got rid of the cast.

But what about the example above? Is this good code design? Or is there a cleaner way? I just feel like initializing fields from constructors the above way is weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, casting like this is error-prone, because the compiler has no easy way of telling that it's going to fail.

However, it looks like the root of the problem is lack of access to the `ServerUri` property, so you added a cast as a workaround. If that is the case, you should be able to have it both ways - keep the interface, and have access to the property, if you can add a new interface:

```
public interface ISessionWithServerUri : ISession { // Come up with a better name
    Uri ServerUri {get;}
}
```

Now your `Session` class can implement `ISessionWithServerUri`, letting you change the declaration of `_session` from `Session` class to `ISessionWithServerUri` interface:

```
internal DataClass : IDataClass
{
    private readonly ISessionWithServerUri _session;

    public DataClass(ISessionWithServerUri session)
    {
        _session = session; // Look, no cast!
    }

    // some more methods that access the internal property _session.ServerUri
    // and call methods on the session object
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I actually wanted the `ServerUri` property to be `internal` which is not possible with the property declared in an interface. Would the right approach be to make the `ISessionWithServerUri` interface `internal`?

Comment: @ebeeb If you would rather keep `ServerUri` internal, you can make `ISessionWithServerUri` internal. This should work, because your `DataClass` is internal as well.

Comment: Sorry to untick the accepted answer but this cannot solve the problem.
Thus the user of the library instantiates the `Session` class, regardless of making the `ISessionWithServerUri` interface `internal`, he will be able to access the `ServerUri` property, because an interface implementation requires the property to be `public`. Derive `ISession` from `ISessionWithServerUri` would not work, either, because public interfaces cannot inherit from `internal` ones.

Comment: @ebeeb "The user of the library instantiates the Session class ..." That's the problem - your `Session` class cannot be publicly visible. You should not force the users of the library to write `new Session()` - `ISession` must be all that he can see. Give users a class that makes `ISession` objects for them (which of course would produce `Session` objects behind the scene). The only reason I said you would be able to make `ISessionWithServerUri` internal is that I saw that your `DataClass` was internal.

Comment: basically you would suggest the factory pattern, that's what I am gonna go with. Thanks for your input, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly I think your current system isn't a good idea.

Your constructor is declaring "I'll take anything as long as it implements `ISession`", but that's not *really* true - calling code could find this out the hard way when they get an `InvalidCastException` upon trying to create a `DataClass` instance.

So you really ought to be declaring `ServerUri` in either `ISession` *or* an interface inherited from `ISession` - but in either case, you need to  declare (and store) this dependency by interface only on `DataClass`

Answer (score 3):

Since `DataClass` depends on `Session` then it should declare that it in its constructor. Any clients of that class should be able to create a valid instance from the types/contracts defined in the constructor.

If you want to depend on an interface, then you should create a new one with the members you require e.g.

```
public interface IUriSession : ISession
{
   Uri ServerUri { get; }
}
```

and change your constructor to

```
public DataClass(IUriSession session) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would always try to avoid the explicit type casts like you have in the constructor.  I am assuming you are using an IoC container to resolve your dependencies, and if the concrete type mapping ever changed to a different class that implemented that interface (and didn't have that internal property) this would obviously break.  It also kind of defeats the purpose of the dependency injection being used in that class.

Are you able to change the DataClass's constructor to inject a different type?  If so, you could create an interface that implemented ISession and also contained that ServerUri property, create a class that implemented the new interface and then inject that type into your constructor (the interface).

Comment: It was not for dependency injection, the reason was unit testing. Thus one cannot mock a concrete class type, just interfaces.